# Copy Between Workbooks and Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a dynamic range from one workbook1 sheet1 to workbook2 sheet2. The code works but only when I have workbook1 sheet1 active, if I have workbook1 sheet2 active the code fail.

My code is:

```
Sub CopyOrders()


    Dim wB1 As Worksheet
    Set wB1 = Workbooks("Master.xlsx").Worksheets("Data")

    Dim RngCe1 As Range
    Set RngCe1 = wB1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11)

    Dim RngCe2 As Range
    Set RngCe2 = wB1.Range("A1:A7000").FIND("Grand Total", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(-1, 23)

    Dim NewRng As Range
    Set NewRng = Range(RngCe1.Address & ":" & RngCe2.Address)

    Dim wB2 As Worksheet
    Set wB2 = Workbooks("Report.xlsx").Worksheets("Orders")

    Dim DesRng As Range
    Set DesRng = wB2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 12)

    NewRng.Copy
    DesRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Your variable names are a bit confusing, because you name a worksheet `wB1`. And please state line and error message.

Comment: OK look wB1 is workbook Master.xlsx with sheet Data and wB2 is another workbook Report.xlsx with sheet Orders, I don’t have error if I use wB1.Activate the code run successfully, the problem is I don’t want to use activate and I thing I must fully qualify the code, the problem arise when I have click in another sheet of the workbook Master and then a blank range copied to workbook Report. How can I fix this to avoid activate the sheets between workbooks to copy ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
Set DesRng = wB2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 12)
```

Instead of `Rows.Count` you need to specify the worksheet here, otherwise the active worksheet is being used. So `wB2.Rows.Count` will do the trick.

And still: you are defining work**sheet** variables and call them w**B**2. Consider renaming them to w**S**2 for clarity.

Comment: Yes!!!! That’s do the trick, it work fine now I knew that I have to fully clarify the code but I miss this. It is better to declare the workbooks and the worksheets separate?

Comment: Well, it's a matter of taste. I would say it is not necessary but personally I would do it in this case. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it OK for you!